# having difficulty setting up phpepub library

Tags: php, epub

i have **downloaded** phpepub via composer 
then started to run the test **file** to understand how to use the library but it throws an error

> Class 'com\grandt\EPub' not found

and then i started to view the test **folder** and opened the file exampletest1.php which also threw an error saying that

> Class 'PHPePub\Core\Logger' not found

i'm thinking a way of working out this error for a while now checked the privileges (which is fine) also the file is also present in the folder 
here is the file structure of the library

```js
phpepub/
 legacy/
 src/
  PHPePub/
   Core/
    structure/
    Logger.php
    .
    .
    .
   Helpers/
 tests/
  demo/
  EPub.Example1.php
  .
  .
  .
  composer.json 
 vendor/
  composer/
  grandt/
  phpzip/
  .
  .
  .
 README.md
 test.php 
 ReadMe.html 
 .
 .
 .
 .
 composer.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to require the `vendor/autoload.php` file in each file where you're using components installed using composer.

test.php :

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

//...
```

test/exampletest1.php

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php');

//...
```

See [Basic Usage - Autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) in Composer Documentation.

#### Usage in your projects

In the root directory of your project, add `"grandt/phpepub": ">=4.0.3"` to your composer dependencies and run `composer install`.

Let's say your project directory structure is :

```
project
  vendor
  public
    index.php
  composer.json
```

When you run `composer install`, Composer creates a directory `vendor/` in the project root and generates an `autoload` file `vendor/autoload.php`.

To use the installed libraries in index.php, require the autoload file :

index.php :

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__."/../vendor/autoload.php";

//...
```

For a quick detailed explanation, try reading [Juan Treminio - Composer Namespaces in 5 minutes](https://jtreminio.com/2012/10/composer-namespaces-in-5-minutes/)